# jamplus: link command line too long for osx

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, jam

I'm using jamplus to build a vendor's cross-platform project. On osx, the C tool's command line (fed via clang to ld) is too long.

Response files are the classic answer to command lines that are too long: jamplus states in the manual that one can generate them on the fly.

The [example in the manual](http://jamplus.org/git/jamplus/docs/html/jam_language.html) looks like this:

```
actions response C++
{
    $(C++) @@(-filelist @($(2)))
}
```

Almost there! If I specifically blow out the C.Link command, like this:

```
actions response C.Link
{
    "$(C.LINK)" $(LINKFLAGS) -o $(<[1]:C) -Wl,-filelist,@($(2:TC)) $(NEEDLIBS:TC) $(LINKLIBS:TC))
}
```

in my jamfile, I get the command line I need that passes through to the linker, but the response file isn't newline terminated, so link fails (osx ld requires newline-separated entries).

1. Is there a way to expand a jamplus list joined with newlines? I've tried using the join expansion `$(LIST:TCJ=\n)` without luck. `$(LIST:TCJ=@(\n))` doesn't work either. If I can do this, the generated file would hopefully be correct.
2. If not, what jamplus code can I use to override the link command for clang, and generate the contents on the fly from a list? I'm looking for the least invasive way of handling this - ideally, modifying/overriding the tool directly, instead of adding new indirect targets wherever a link is required - since it's our vendor's codebase, as little edit as possible is desired.

Comment: If someone viewing this with more than 1500 reputation could create and add a jamplus tag, that would be awesome.

Comment: added jamplus tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
newLine = "
" ;

actions response C.Link
{
    "$(C.LINK)" $(LINKFLAGS) -o $(<[1]:C) -Wl,-filelist,@($(2:TCJ=$(newLine))) $(NEEDLIBS:TC) $(LINKLIBS:TC))
}
```

To be clear (I'm not sure how StackOverflow will format the above), the newLine variable should be defined by typing:

```
newLine = "" ;
```

And then placing the carat between the two quotes and hitting enter. You can use this same technique for certain other characters, i.e.

```
tab = "    " ;
```

Again, start with newLine = "" and then place carat between the quotes and hit tab. In the above it is actually 4 spaces which is wrong, but hopefully you get the idea. Another useful one to have is:

```
dollar = "$" ;
```

The last one is useful as $ is used to specify variables typically, so having a dollar variable is useful when you actually want to specify a dollar literal. For what it is worth, the Jambase I am using (the one that ships with the JamPlus I am using), has this:

```
SPACE = " " ;
TAB = " " ;
NEWLINE = "
" ;
```

Around line 28...

Comment: I see NEWLINE in my jamplus jambase also. Even though it's been more than a year ago, I'm excited to try this out.

Comment: I swapped in $(NEWLINE), and I can see the contents of the response file, as printed out by jamplus, are now separated correctly. You're awesome, Steven! This totally killed me. Updating yours to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. I gave up on trying to use escaped newlines and other language-specific characters within string joins. Maybe there's an awesome way to do that, that was too thorny to discover.
2. Use a multi-step shell command with multiple temp files.

For jamplus (and maybe other jam variants), the section of the `actions response {}` between the curly braces becomes an inline shell script. And the response file syntax `@(<value>)` returns a filename that can be assigned within the shell script, with the contents set to `<value>`.

Thus, code like:

```
actions response C.Link
{
    _RESP1=@($(2:TCJ=#)#$(NEEDLIBS:TCJ=#)#$(LINKLIBS:TCJ=#))
    _RESP2=@()
    perl -pe "s/[#]/\n/g" < $_RESP1 > $_RESP2
    "$(C.LINK)" $(LINKFLAGS) -o $(<[1]:C) -Wl,-filelist,$_RESP2
}
```

creates a pair of temp files, assigned to shell variable names `_RESP1` and `_RESP2`. File at path `_RESP1` is assigned the contents of the expanded sequence joined with a `#` character. Search and replace is done with a perl one liner into `_RESP2`. And link proceeds as planned, and jamplus cleans up the intermediate files.

I wasn't able to do this with characters like `:;\n`, but `#` worked as long as it had no adjacent whitespace. Not completely satisfied, but moving on.

Comment: Yeah, but this affects the C.Link command for all projects when using SubDirs, and it can break the other ones. Would be great to know, how can I apply this to exactly one target.

Comment: Ah. Adding any empty lists here (only `$2` is guaranteed to be assigned) breaks the entire thing. Rethinking.

Comment: I ended up replacing this with a temporary inline / heredoc script in the interpreted language of my choice, and invoking that. It wasn't pretty, but it handles all my corner cases now.